How to wait for child processes to complete
I have a BASH script that immediately exits while launching a child process that runs in the background. This child process can spawn its own child processes an unknown number of times over an extended period. Also, I can't edit the script, I can only run it.
How can I wait for the completion of all processes spawned by this script?
P.S. the child processes started by the script, and then by the child process itself, are Linux xterm

@G.M. told you yesterday how to do it, source the parent script and add a wait.

When you are run a sub processes it's back his pids. Command wait can wait  wait <process or job ID>. Command waitpid can you help too then you have a list of running sub processes. From process to process you can send param as pid or used in subprocess subfunction for watch ps .From the ps man page, the status field will tell you if a thread is on the run queue (use the 'L' option to see threads) .
Create true logic of your program.

I know about the wait command, but the problem is getting the PID of the processes, because I don't have access to edit the script code that generates them.

you known name of script. Use ps for found all thread or cat /proc/<PID>/status for find a sub PID your process(param  PPid)

I tried ps -l. I only see the main child process being started by the script, and its PPID = 1, which is not the script's PID. I don't see any child processes of this child process.

show logic or code. if PPID=1 then a systemd is run it.
